# I need help rewriting problems using arrow functions

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions

So I am learning arrow functions and to practice them I'm trying to redo old problems but using arrow functions.

```
const isDivis = ( int % 3 === 0 || int % 5 === 0) => ? true : false;

isDivis(15);
```

The result should tell you if 15 is divisible by 3 or 5 which is true in this case.

Comment: `const isDivis = int =>  int % 3 === 0 || int % 5 === 0` ?

Comment: Awesome thank you.

Comment: Rewrite *solutions* instead, friend.

Answer (score 0):

`const isDivis = ( int ) => int % 3 === 0 || int % 5 === 0`
You can get more insight about arrow functions here [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Answer (score 0):

You are syntactically wrong.... It should be

`(Arguments) => {
    function_body;
}`

So In your case

`const isDivis = (number) => number%3===0 || number%5 ===0`

More clearly
`const isDivis = (number) => {
    return number % 3 === 0 || number % 5 === 0;
}`